# Dynamic memory allocation in C

Tags: c, memory, malloc

what is the main difference between how memory that is allocated using malloc and memory that is allocated when a non-pointer variable is declared in C?

Comment: Lifetime. An automatic object's lifetime ends when the block in which it is declared is exited. An allocated object's lifetime ends when it is deallocated (or the program ends).

Comment: @EOF There is also the space allocated by the loader for rodata etc.

Comment: ... which is why Imma close-voting this as 'too broad'.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are asking about returning a pointer to object.

For example, say we have a struct called `foo`:

```
struct foo
{
    int bar;
}
```

Using `malloc()` to create a new `foo` object:

```
foo *newFoo1(void)
{
    foo *ptr = malloc(sizeof (struct foo));
    ptr -> bar = 42;
    return ptr;
}
```

`newFoo1()` allocates a block of memory on the **heap** to `ptr`, and then all initialisations are made. Finally, `ptr` is returned. After `newFoo()` returns, the lifetime of `*ptr` doesn't end, because it resides on the heap, which won't be overridden.

Otherwise, you may simply returning pointer to local variable:

```
foo *newFoo2(void)
{
    foo aFoo;
    aFoo.bar = 42;
    return &aFoo;
}
```

In this case, `aFoo` resides on the **stack**. When `newFoo2()` returns, the lifetime of `aFoo` immediately ends. The corresponding memory may not be overridden immediately, but all information `aFoo` contains will eventually be lost after one or more functions are called.